# I want to send a packet through bunch of specific ip address. which command would allow me to do that?

Tags: networking

I want to decide complete path a TCP Packet will take and I want it to route through specific IP addresses. Is this possible? If yes, then how to do it and which commands/utilities to use?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, mind adding some additional information? Do you want to route the packet via a specific network interface on your machine? Do you want to route it via a specific router on your local network? Do you want to route the packet over a specific set of routers on the Internet?

Comment: You can control the first router the packet goes to by modifying/adding a new default route on your system.

Comment: There are security implications, but this question might fit better on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But you can *only* control that first hop.  After that, the first hop router will decide what to do next.

Comment: There's no way we can know whether what you're trying to do is possible or not because you haven't described it in sufficient detail. It *may* be possible.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is source routing, where the sender decides about the path the packet will take through the network. While this is in theory supported by IP in practice it will be ignored or such packets will be discarded since this is considered a security problem.

For more information see the [Wikipedia article on Source Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing).